# Firebase functions return 404

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to set up a custom domain for firebase functions.
Custom domain already verified and works fine.
My firebase functions run under `us-central1`:

[image]

here is my code for `login` function:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require(`express`);
const cors = require(`cors`);
const admin = require(`firebase-admin`);
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const appLogin = express();
appLogin.use(cors({origin:true}));

appLogin.post("/", async(req:Request, res:Response)=>{
    functions.logger.log(`received`);
    const body = req.body;
    functions.logger.log(body);
    const result = await firestore.collection(DbCollections.USER).add(body);
    return res.status(201).send(JSON.stringify({"user_id":result.id}));
}); 


exports.login = functions.https.onRequest(appLogin);
```

nothing super fancy...

So, when I am using url from screenshot in postman - it works fine.
But I want to use custom domain like next:

```
https://mydomai.com/api/login
```

Here is my `firebase.json` hosting section:

```json
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/login",
        "function": "login"
      }
    ]
  }
```

But when I am trying to reach `login` with custom domain - it returns me `404` without any valuable error message:
[image]

[image]

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `source` of a rewrite is not removed from the URL in the call to the function, so you likely want to change `appLogin.post("/", ...)` to `appLogin.post("/api/login/", ...)`.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it!